# How do I take the result from a dropdown and use it as an index to a dataframe and populate a chart in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have this bit of code,

```
selectInput('countrySelect', 'Country', mylist)
```

myList is a list of 100+ countries and I need to retrieve the index when a country is selected and use it to create a chart.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 


  output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = dates, y=DATA_ALL_DF[1, 2:18], type = "l")
  })
```

The index of 1 in the DATA_ALL_DF dataframe is the place I need the dynamic index to work.

Comment: `plot(x = dates, y=DATA_ALL_DF[as.numeric(input$countrySelect), 2:18], type = "l")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a complete example, but this should do it.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 


  output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$countrySelect)
    idx <- which(input$countrySelect==mylist)
    plot(x = dates, y=DATA_ALL_DF[idx, 2:18], type = "l")
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I put that in I get this error "need finite 'ylim' values". The index works if I just put a number in there i.e. 1. But not sure why it doesnt work

Comment: Post your whole program. Hard to tell what is wrong otherwise.

Comment: Actually I just changed the input$countrySelect==mylist bit from a list to a DF and that worked, and did the trick. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Also curious as to what list you mean. I don't see a list anywhere.

Comment: Sure, myList was a converted list

Comment: Thank you so much again, very helpful. Might contact you again if I need anything further

Comment: Sure. You can most easly find me on Linked In probably.

Comment: Hi Mike, would you mind taking a look at my other questions? As you were so helpful before?

Comment: Sure, for an upvote :). But I need to see to some other things first, but I will get around to it.